# Maven - replace java files during project build

Tags: maven

My question is:
I have java project and before compilation I need to replace some java files with custom files from external folder.
I tried build-helper-maven-plugin:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>custom_scr_directory</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

But is seems that it does not replace files, just add new source folder and that is why I have 'duplicate class' exception during compilation because files have the same names as in the main project.

Comment: What do you mean by replace? Do you mean filtering?

Comment: I mean replace files from my main scr by java files from custom folder before compilation

Comment: Which means you are using the files from the custom folder. Why not moving them to the *src/main/java* folder?

Comment: I cannot move them to main folder. I need to take them only in several cases. All other times project must be built with files from main folder.

Comment: That sounds a little bit strange. Furthermore sounds like you need some profiles...But what is the purpose of this approach?

Comment: Can you give example with profiles? I found one solution here - [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194338/replace-a-source-file-in-maven-compile), but probably exists more simple way.

Answer (score 1):

A similar question is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3194338/replace-a-source-file-in-maven-compile) (spoiler: antrun)

After all, build-helper:add-source would not do the trick, (it is intended to do what it does: add another source directory), you can safely drop it.

UPD: And yes, +1 to what khmarbaise said: you'll need profiles to make this goal conditional.